# Why is openCV mask turning the whole image black?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

The first image is the original, the second is the hsv, and the third is the mask.

The yellowest color in the hsv image is between the boundaries set. Why is the whole image turning black?

[image: Original]

[image: HSV]

[image: Mask]

```py
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import imutils

    directory = r"C:\\Users\\colin\\Documents\\projects\\dataset\\"
    i = 0
    for entry in os.scandir(directory):
        if (entry.path.endswith(".png")) and (i == 0):
            img = cv2.imread(directory + str(entry.name))
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            i += 1
            lower_range = np.array([27,132,156])
            upper_range = np.array([33,138,162])
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
            cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\colin\\Documents\\projects\\mask.png',mask)
```

Comment: Could you please describe what are you trying to do?

Comment: the yellow color area in the second image has values: H=120; S=192; V=217

Comment: @Rivers I am testing the openCV inRange() function. Ultimately, I need everything but the letters in the image to be one color so I can find contours and split those into separate images.

Comment: try inRange with ranges 100-130, 0-255, 0-255 on the HSV image

Comment: would still be interesting why you thought the yellow color would be within the boundaries you specified?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about your color ranges, you can either change the values manually and randomly or maybe take a look at this color seperator script it can be very helpful [hsv color seperator](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator)